# Skype for business tag for status change alerts log?

Tags: skype

I like the status change alert in skype for business
But I wish I can have log for when I am not around

is there a log file that keeps a record when a user becomes available?

I checked in

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\Tracing
```

But did not notice any log for user becoming available

thanks

[image]